# How much memory takes a C program

Tags: c, memory, assembly, memory-management

I am developping an in memory database as a side project which is supposed to be lightweight. I haven't been promming in C since school and my knowledge of computer architecure is limited...

I am wondering how can I calculate exactly how much memory my program will take and from which kind of memory (RAM, register, ... ).
The most obvious is everything I allocate through malloc. Sorry if the following questions are a bit random...

1. Global variables will be stored in RAM? Does the keyword static (to limit the scope) influence anything?
2. Are all global variable allocated at the same time or could it be lazy allocated on first access?
3. Is the executable loaded in memory? Does an executable of 1MB will take 1MB for the execution?

This subject is a pretty big one so don't hesitate to point me to a book or a website. I guess it's not only about C but more about the computer architecture, the assembly code etc.

Comment: I'm surprised a member with 2k rep would ask such a question. Please be specific

Comment: If you're on a modern desktop OS then all sections from the executable file is *mapped* into the process memory map, but nor all sections or parts of the file may actually be loaded into memory, and when it's loaded into memory the program and its allocated memory may not be in RAM at all but swapped out to disk (it's all in "memory" but just not in the RAM memory).

Comment: Also read about memory layout of a C program

Comment: This link describes the memory layout of a C program and contains further links to related material. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Comment: @darknight I am a very good java developper but obviously a terrible C programmer. Memory is not really your first concern in Java ^^

Comment: I really don't get the down votes.I know how stupid my questions can sound to an experienced developper, but well I have to start somewhere...

Comment: What kind of computer is this supposed to run on ? A full workstation with Windows or Linux, some handheld device with a few MB of RAM or a microcontroller with 64K of RAM ? Be more specific. If it's Windows/Linux, you probably don't need to worry about memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming typical computing platforms, not embedded systems.

> Global variables will be stored in RAM? Does the keyword static (to limit the scope) influence anything?

Global variables will be stored in RAM only if the operating system thinks that's the best use for RAM. Scope has no effect.

> Are all global variable allocated at the same time or could it be lazy allocated on first access?

It depends what you mean by "allocated". Typically virtual memory (address space) is allocated all at once, but physical memory (RAM) is allocated as needed.

> Is the executable loaded in memory? Does an executable of 1MB will take 1MB for the execution?

It is mapped into memory at program start. It is actually loaded into physical memory as needed and evicted from physical memory as the OS deems appropriate.

I strongly suspect you are looking for simple answers to very complex questions.

Comment: You strongly suspect right! I am just starting just need few pointers...

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but that doesn't mean they're all *mapped* at any given point in time.
2. They can't be lazily allocated, depending on what you mean by that. They will all mapped to virtual addresses, but then again if the program never accesses the variables the OS might never need to map those addresses to actual physical RAM.
3. It depends, but most modern desktop/server operating systems will page the code in as needed, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Oups, that's an interesting question, but the answer is as usual : it depends !

Your questions are heavily implementation dependent. In old (now outdated) systems, existed the notion of overlays : parts of code were only loaded in memory when needed. I do not think it is still used with modern virtual memory systems, but it could have sense on embedded systems with llimited resources.

And some compilers generally have options to determine the size of the stack. It can be determinant for a lightweight program.

And there is obvious dependancy on architecture : on Unix-Linux, you have elf vs. a.out format with different memory requirement and management, on Windows, there is still the old .com format that can lead to really tiny executables.